# Filtering out values off a threshold using KStream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to use Java KStream in Kafka to filter out all that values that are exceeding a certain value. Values are exchanged as JSON, for example:

```
ConsumerRecord(topic=u'test', partition=0, offset=1109, timestamp=1528110096230L, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value='{"device":"Internal","sensor":"Phone Microphone","value":"72.1"}', checksum=None, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=64)
```

I want to filter out values that are below 20.0 (in the above case, the value is 72.1 and it's okay)

```
public class WordCountExample {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "Filter");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "andrewnetwork.ddns.net:9095");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");


    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("test");

    source =  source
    .filterNot((k,v) -> {
        if(isParsableAsDouble(v) && Double.parseDouble(v) <= 50.0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    });

    source.to("mem");
```

Filtering does not happen and I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: Below 20 or 50? Also, are you sure `filterNot` is what you want? Also, if values are JSON, `parseDouble` won't parse objects

Comment: When you process `(k,v)`, `v` is the same as `value='{"device":"Internal","sensor":"Phone Microphone","value":"72.1"}'`, ie, the whole JSON object. Thus, you need to extract "value:72.1" from `v` and apply the comparison to that.

Answer (score 3):

By putting `isParsableAsDouble(v)` within a `filterNot`, you're filtering out everything because JSON isn't parsable as a double. I believe you're misunderstanding between Kafka values and the `value` field within the JSON, which is not automatically extracted.

You'll need a JSON deserializer. [For example](https://github.com/amient/hello-kafka-streams/blob/master/src/main/java/io/amient/examples/wikipedia/WikipediaStreamDemo.java)

```
    final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);


    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // load props 

    KStream<Bytes, JsonNode> source = builder.stream(Serdes.BytesSerde(), jsonSerde, "test")
        .filter((k, v) -> {
            return v.get("value").asDouble() > 20.0;
         });
```

Comment: I solved by decomposing the JSON with the standard JSON library into the predicate method, and changing filternot to filter. I then returned true when the JSON field I required was above a threshold, and false when not.

Comment: Cool. You probably should put the JSON in a map function before the filter, but that's fine. Feel free to either accept this answer using checkmark next to the post, or provide your own answer with your solution